# How to write a query to get the latest employee record given the effective date in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a employee and employee_history table. For every update on employee table, I insert a record into the employee_history table.

Both the tables have a column called as effective date which indicates that the employee status as on that effective date.

Below are my two tables.

[image]

I need to get the employee record latest as on that effective date.

e.g If I need to get the employee as on 16 may I should get the emp_hist_id = 2 record from history table. As on 5 june  I should get the emp_hist_id = 4 from hist table.

And as on 15th August I should get the record from employee table itself.

Please help.

Comment: Why not store the current employee record in employee_history too?  Then you would only need to query employee_history to get data for any date.

Answer (score 3):

You could try something like

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT * FROM (
    (SELECT emp_id, name, email, title, region, division, "effective date" 
     FROM employee
     WHERE emp_id = desired_id)
    UNION
    (SELECT emp_id, name, email, title, region, division, "effective date" 
     FROM employee _history
     WHERE emp_id = desired_id)
  ) t
  WHERE t."effective date" <= desired_date
  ORDER by t."effective date" DESC) p
WHERE ROWNUM = 1
```

The idea is to take records related to desired user from both tables, then take dates lower than desired one and finally catch the first

Comment: I think you need to replace the `[` `]` with `"` `"` (assuming the column name is  `"effective date"` and not `effective_date`

Comment: @Marco. Thanks for the answer. What if I need the list of all the employees and not just one employee with their status as on effective date?

Comment: @Ashish It looks like based on his Query that if you remove the "WHERE ROWNUM = 1" It will then show all rows thus giving you all employees. I'm not positive but test that out.

Comment: @Tony318. I tried removing  "WHERE ROWNUM = 1" and then it gives multiple entries for a employee. I think we need to group by employee id order by effective date desc and then take the top row from each group.

Comment: @Ashish Try doing what you said, if that doesn't work doing a SELECT DISTINCT on the emp_id should narrow results to 1 entry per employee but still allow multiple employees to show.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this problem without analytic functions.  The subquery here calculates the most recent effective date in the history record before the employee effective date:

```
select e.*
from employee_history eh join
     (select e.employee_id, max(eh.effective_date) as latest_effective_date
      from employee e join
           employee_history eh
           on e.employee_id = eh.employee_id and
              e.effective_date >= eh.effective_date
     ) ehl
     on eh.employee_id = ehl.employee_id and
        eh.effective_date = ehl.effective_date
```

This solution assumes that there are no duplicate effective dates in the history table.  If there are, then you have another option.  Assuming the employee_history_ids are assigned sequentially, take the max of that id instead of the date.

There are alternative formulations of the solution using Oracle's analytic functions.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following :

```
SELECT *
FROM
  (SELECT e.emp_id,
          e.name,
          e.email,
          e.title,
          e.region,
          e.division,
          e.effective_date,
          row_number() over (partition BY e.emp_id
                             ORDER BY e.effective_date DESC) rn
   FROM employee e
   UNION ALL 
   SELECT eh.emp_id,
          eh.name,
          eh.email,
          eh.title,
          eh.region,
          eh.division,
          eh.effective_date,
          row_number() over (partition BY eh.emp_id
                             ORDER BY eh.effective_date DESC) rn
   FROM employee_history eh)
WHERE effective_date < to_date('15/06/2012','DD/MM/YYYY')
  AND rn = 1
```

you can see a better example [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3a25f/2)